# gcc, arm cortex, collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit

Tags: gcc, makefile, linker, cross-compiling

I have this makefile and Im trying to compile using cygwin.
I have this linker error make collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status error, and I don't know how to get rid of it.

```
######################################
# target
######################################
TARGET = blinkingled


######################################
# building variables
######################################

# optimization
OPT = -Og


#######################################
# paths
#######################################
# Build path
BUILD_DIR = build

######################################
# source
######################################
# C sources
SRCS      = main_cm0plus.c
SRCS      += system_tviibe1m_cm0plus.c
SRCS      += startup.c
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/adc/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/canfd/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/cpu/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/crypto/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/dma/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/evtgen/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/flash/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/gpio/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/ipc/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/lin/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/lvd/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/mcwdt/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/mpu/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/prot/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/scb/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/smartio/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/srom/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/sysclk/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/sysflt/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/sysint/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/syslib/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/syspm/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/sysreset/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/sysrtc/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/systick/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/syswdt/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/tcpwm/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/drivers/trigmux/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/interrupts/rev_d/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/mw/button/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/mw/flash/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/semihosting/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/swtimer/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/startup/*.c)
SRCS      += $(wildcard src/system/*.c)

# ASM sources
ASM_SOURCES =  "C:/data/traveo/TVII_Sample_Driver_Library_7.1.0/tviibe1m/src/startup_cm0plus.s"
#startup_cm0plus.s 


#######################################
# binaries
#######################################
PREFIX = arm-none-eabi-
# The gcc compiler bin path can be either defined in make command via GCC_PATH variable (> make GCC_PATH=xxx)
# either it can be added to the PATH environment variable.
ifdef GCC_PATH
CC = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)size
else
CC = $(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(PREFIX)size
endif
HEX = $(CP) -O ihex
BIN = $(CP) -O binary -S
 
#######################################
# CFLAGS
#######################################
# cpu
CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m0plus

# fpu
FPU = -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16

# float-abi
FLOAT-ABI = -mfloat-abi=soft

# mcu
MCU = $(CPU) -mthumb $(FPU) $(FLOAT-ABI)

# macros for gcc
# AS defines
AS_DEFS = 

# C defines
#C_DEFS = ../../


# AS includes
AS_INCLUDES = 

# C includes

INCDIRS = ../../common/hdr
INCDIRS += ../../common/hdr/cmsis/include
INCDIRS += ../../common/src/drivers
INCDIRS += ../../common/src/drivers/sysclk
INCDIRS += ../../common/src/drivers/flash
INCDIRS += ../../common/src/drivers/syslib
INCDIRS += ../../common/src/drivers/mcwdt
INCDIRS += ../../tviibe1m/hdr/rev_d
INCDIRS += ../../tviibe1m/hdr/rev_d/ip
INCDIRS += ../../tviibe1m/src/system/rev_d
INCDIRS += ../../tviibe1m/hdr/rev_d/mcureg
INCDIRS += ../../tviibe1m/src/drivers/
INCDIRS += ../../common/src/drivers/syswdt
INCDIRS += ../../common/src/mw

INCLUDE   = $(addprefix -I,$(INCDIRS))

# compile gcc flags
ASFLAGS = $(MCU) $(AS_DEFS) $(AS_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

CFLAGS = $(MCU) $(C_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -mthumb -mno-thumb-interwork -mfpu=vfp -msoft-float  

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
CFLAGS += -g -gdwarf-2
endif

# My C flags:
CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-variable

# Generate dependency information
CFLAGS += -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)"


#######################################
# LDFLAGS
#######################################
# link script
LDSCRIPT = "c:/data/traveo/TVII_Sample_Driver_Library_7.1.0/tviibe1m/src/linker.ld"

# libraries
LIBS = -lc -lm -lnosys 
LIBDIR = 
LDFLAGS = $(MCU) --specs=nano.specs -T$(LDSCRIPT) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) -Wl,-Map=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections

# default action: build all

all: $(TARGET)
blinkingled: main_cm0plus.o system_tviibe1m_cm0plus.o startup.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
    
    
main_cm0plus.o: main_cm0plus.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main_cm0plus.c
    
system_tviibe1m_cm0plus.o: system_tviibe1m_cm0plus.c cy_project.h cy_device_headers.h 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) system_tviibe1m_cm0plus.c
    
    
startup.o: startup.c startup_customize.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) startup.c
    
BIN_NAME  = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR), $(TARGET))

.PHONY: all
all: $(BIN_NAME).elf
all: $(BIN_NAME).bin
all: $(BIN_NAME).s19
all: $(BIN_NAME).hex
all: $(BIN_NAME).lst
all: print_size


%.bin: %.elf
    $(CP) -O binary -S $< $@

%.s19: %.elf
    $(CP) -O srec -S $< $@

%.hex: %.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex -S $< $@

%.lst: %.elf
    $(CP) -d $< > $@

.PHONY: print_size
print_size: $(BIN_NAME).elf
    $(SIZE) $<



#######################################
# build the application
#######################################
# list of objects
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o)))
vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(C_SOURCES)))
# list of ASM program objects
OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(ASM_SOURCES:.s=.o)))
vpath %.s $(sort $(dir $(ASM_SOURCES)))

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c makefile | $(BUILD_DIR) 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.s makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(AS) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) makefile
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    $(SZ) $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.hex: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(HEX) $< $@
    
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.bin: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(BIN) $< $@    
    
$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir $@        

#######################################
# clean up
#######################################
clean:
    -rm -fR $(BUILD_DIR)
  
#######################################
# dependencies
#######################################
-include $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/*.d)

# *** EOF ***
```

this is the error im getting:

```
c:/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: c:/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi
-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v6-m/nofp\libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): in function `exit':
exit.c:(.text.exit+0x18): undefined reference to `_exit'
c:/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:\cygwin64\tmp\cc8Euh2e.o
: in function `main':
main_cm0plus.c:(.text.main+0x2): undefined reference to `SystemInit'
c:/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: main_cm0plus.c:(.text.main
+0xa): undefined reference to `Cy_SysEnableApplCore'
c:/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: main_cm0plus.c:(.text.main
+0x14): undefined reference to `Cy_GPIO_Pin_Init'
c:/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: main_cm0plus.c:(.text.main
+0x1a): undefined reference to `Cy_SysTick_DelayInUs'
c:/tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10-2020-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: main_cm0plus.c:(.text.main
+0x28): undefined reference to `__cm4_vector_base_linker_symbol'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:172: main_cm0plus.o] Error 1
```

line 172 is:

```
main_cm0plus.o: main_cm0plus.c 
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main_cm0plus.c
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to compile a source file into an object file: turning `main_cm0plus.c` into `main_cm0plus.o`.

These errors clearly show that you are trying to LINK this file into an executable, instead.

The compiler decides what to generate based on what flags you give it.  The default behavior is to take the command line arguments and create an executable.  If you want to generate an object file, you tell the compiler to only do those steps by adding the `-c` option (see the documentation for your compiler).

So, your makefile rule is wrong, it should be:

```
main_cm0plus.o: main_cm0plus.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) main_cm0plus.c
```

(note, adding the `-c` option here).  Even better is to use automatic variables:

```
main_cm0plus.o: main_cm0plus.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Just note that your other pattern rule that compiles files, has a lot of other flags there which you may also need.  You should ask yourself why you're writing new rules for these specific source files, instead of using the default pattern rule.